# select query into list on one column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-concat

I am trying to select all id into one column and delimit it with a comma `,`

My DATA column:

```
+---+--------+--------------+
|id |somedata|someother data|
+---+--------+--------------+
|1  |data1   |other1        |
+---+--------+--------------+
|2  |data2   |other2        |
+---+--------+--------------+
|3  |data3   |other3        |
+---+--------+--------------+
```

The result I am trying to make:

```
+-------+
|id list|
+-------+
|1, 2, 3|
+-------+
```

The result should be a list of ID's in 1 column named 'id list'.

The question is, is this possible? and how? I tried searching for the keywords `sql query select into list` and other keywords but with no luck.

---

But this query is on a nested select.

Comment: A question like this has been asked and answered a thousand times before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [**GROUP_CONCAT()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS idList FROM tableA
```

Comment: I'm getting syntax error on `INTO`. (edit) oh, I changed `into` to `AS` and it works. thanks.

Comment: I got it. It seemed weird to have the `into` in there. but I'm getting only the last id, example 3 ids in there the result is `3,3,3` instead of `1,2,3`.. And on another note that query is on a nested select.