# Getting multiple rows as a single row in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a basic multi-school management system that I am working on for fun in order to learn querying from a MySQL database.

I am doing a number of joins from tables such as  `students`, `schools`,`student_grade`, `grade_school` etc. I now want to get a list of all subjects the student has been assigned. Since there are multiple possible rows, I have a `student_subject` table to hold the student_id and then the subject_id values.

The following query gets me the student's name, and their grade:

```
SELECT a.id,a.firstnames,a.surname,d.gradename 
FROM students a 
LEFT JOIN student_grade b ON a.id=b.studentid
LEFT JOIN grade_school c ON c.id=b.gradeid
LEFT JOIN grades d ON c.gradeid=d.id
WHERE a.schoolid=? AND b.gradeid=? ORDER by a.surname ASC
```

This results in each row returned to be the student's name and their grade, like this:

```
ID   |   Firstname    |   Surname    |   Grade
 1   |     John       |      Doe     |     4
 5   |      Sarah     |   Marshall   |     7
```

How can I get all the subjects the student is assigned and put them all in a column  "subject_ids" to get a result as follows:

```
ID   |   Firstname    |   Surname    |   Grade  |  Subjects
 1   |     John       |      Doe     |     4    |  5,54,2,56
 5   |      Sarah     |   Marshall   |     7    |  2,4,12,17
```

My table structures are as follows:

```
Table `students`
id | firstnames | surname | schoolid


Table `student_grade`
id | studentid | gradeid


Table `grade_school`
id | gradeid| schoolid


Table `grades`
id | gradename|


Table `student_subject`
id | studentid| subjectid
 4 |    1     |    5
 5 |    1     |    54
 6 |    1     |    2
 7 |    1     |    56
 8 |    5     |    2
 9 |    5     |    4
10 |    5     |    12
11 |    5     |    17
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I concatenate multiple MySQL rows into one field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.id,a.firstnames,a.surname,d.gradename, GROUP_CONCAT(s.subjectid)
FROM students a 
LEFT JOIN student_grade b ON a.id=b.studentid
LEFT JOIN grade_school c ON c.id=b.gradeid
LEFT JOIN grades d ON c.gradeid=d.id
LEFT JOIN student_subject s ON s.studentid=a.id
WHERE a.schoolid=? AND b.gradeid=? ORDER by a.surname ASC
```

also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084354/select-query-into-list-on-one-column) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662207/mysql-results-as-comma-separated-list)

Comment: Thanks, this however only returns one student. But I think I understand the concept.

Comment: maybe add `GROUP BY a.id`

Answer (score 1):

The [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function will do what you want here.

This question is a dup of [Can I concatenate multiple MySQL rows into one field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you, i'll have a look at GROUP_CONCAT()